# Lua Algorithm for saving moves in tic-tac-toe

Tags: lua, save, artificial-intelligence, move, tic-tac-toe

So, I'm programming in lua, and im ATTEMPTING to make AI. Every time i run the code, (I only have the AI's move code in right now) it gives me a random spot drawn on the board, but it doesn't save previous moves. It's an entirely clean board with one space taken. Can anybody help me with this? It would be greatly appreciated if so!
Code:

```
    function moves()
local Possible = {'1,1','1,2','1,3','2,1','2,2','2,3','3,1','3,2','3,3'}
math.randomseed(os.time())
    math.random()
    local AImove = Possible[math.random( #Possible )]
print('The Opponent Chose',AImove)
--[[
removal of numbers from possibility to only provide legal moves0
]]--
if AImove == '1,1' then
    table.remove(Possible,1)
    print("_ _ _") 
    print("_ _ _")
    print("X _ _")
end
if AImove == '1,2' then
    table.remove(Possible,2)
    print("___")
    print("X__")
    print("___")
end
if AImove == '1,3' then
    table.remove(Possible,3) 
    print("X _ _")
    print("_ _ _")
    print("_ _ _")
end
if AImove == '2,1' then
    table.remove(Possible,4)
    print("_ _ _")
    print("_ _ _")
    print("_ X _")
end
if AImove == '2,2' then
    table.remove(Possible,5)
    print("_ _ _")
    print("_ X _")
    print("_ _ _")
end
if AImove == '2,3' then
    table.remove(Possible,6)
    print("_ X _")
    print("_ _ _")
    print("_ _ _")
end
if AImove == '3,1' then
    table.remove(Possible,7)
    print("_ _ _")
    print("_ _ _")
    print("_ _ X")
end
if AImove == '3,2' then
    table.remove(Possible,8)
    print("_ _ _")
    print("_ _ X")
    print("_ _ _")
end
if AImove == '3,3' then
    table.remove(Possible,9)
    print("_ _ X")
    print("_ _ _")
    print("_ _ _")
end
end
moves()
```

Comment: "can anybody help me" is not a good question. show what you have tried. share your code and ask something specific. you'll need something that stores the board's state across turns. please read [ask]

Comment: Okayayayayayayay

Comment: Im trying to add 4 spaces in all code lines, but it keeps saying i need to format it with 4 spaces. Im on mobile right now, so i can't do CTRL+K

Comment: nevermind i fixed the formatting

Comment: no, you did not :) Use proper indentation, helps a lot at reading the code

Comment: I don't really understand whats your plan, but hardcoding the game seems overkill. What will you do in the next turn? Provide all 9*7 possible turns? I think what you want here is a minimax algorithm for the AI and an array of length 9 for the game state. Which you can print without the massive code duplication you currently have :)

Comment: Im a beginner in lua, okay? I don't know every solution to everything, and I'm on mobile right now so i dont get how i can get minimax. Sometimes hardcoding is done because of limitations

Comment: Also @piglet how exactly would i find something like that?

Comment: Wait nvm lol minimax is an algorithm not an extension providing functions. Apologies for stupidity 

Comment: Before making an AI you should make the game itself. You're now just picking from 9 random prints. You need to implement game states, taking turns, user input etc., before even beginning to work on an AI

Comment: Okay, but how exactly would i implement minimax into lua?

Comment: the proper way would be to learn the basics of programming befor or at least in parallel to your game development. you cannot build a house if you don't know the basic tools an bricks. you need some datastructure that stores the game state. in Lua you would implement that using a table. once you have that gamestate you can implement something that manipulates that game state... tic tac toe is a very common programming problem. there are countless tutorials out there which you can follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something that stores the state of the game. I'll give you a very simple quick and dirty example. A table `board` that stores the 9 fields and a few functions that allow us to manipulate and display the board.

This should give you a rough idea on how to get started.

```
-- our board
local board = {
}

-- check a field on our board
function board:check(row, col, str)
  board[row][col] = str
  self:print()
end

-- print the board to the screen
function board:print()
  print("---------")
  for i,v in ipairs(self) do
    print("| " .. table.concat(v, " ") .. " |")
  end
  print("---------")
end

-- init/clear the board
function board:init()
  for row = 1, 3 do
    board[row] = {}
    for col = 1, 3 do
      board[row][col] = " "
    end
  end
  board:print()
end

board:init()
board:check(2,2,"X")
board:check(1,3,"O")
```

Comment: Thanks for this! As a beginner to lua, I'm gonna study the ins and outs of this code.